# Bootstrap slider image getting stretched in responsive view

Tags: css, bootstrap-slider

is there any solution for bootstrap slider image stretch problem for responsive view ? I don't want to set height default

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

I tried with the above slider which is an default slider given in twitter bootstrap. when I included images in that slider it was stretching. If anyone faced this issue let me know the solution

[image: Slider Responsive View - Image Getting Stretched]

Comment: Can you provide your live url or share your code with us?

Comment: am doing locally, sorry i'm not knowing how to share my code in js fiddle. so i have attached snap shot of my responsive view

Comment: Go to https://jsfiddle.net/ and the code to their respective section. On the Left side, Add the Bootstrap Css and Js Link to `External Resources` Tab. It'll be easier for us to debug.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f0y1actq/

Comment: What's the actual size (W x H) of your image?

Comment: width: 1300px ; height: 500px;

Comment: The code is working fine. Have you applied any custom css to image or something like that.

Comment: yeah.. but there is an default height for carousel image so that only image is stretching. if i remove that height it is not working (that is image not getting viewed). i have not included any css or anything other than that bootstrap

Comment: If you give a height to the the image, it'll try to maintain the same height for all the devices. So the slide looks stretched. You need to remove the height property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you already looking for this, but Bootstrap also provides a class for responsive images. Just added it to the img-tag.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/cat/cat-6.jpg"  class="img-responsive" alt="Slider 1">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/cat/cat-6.jpg"  class="img-responsive" alt="Slider 2">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>Caption Text</h3>
     </div>
   </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/cat/cat-6.jpg"  class="img-responsive" alt="Slider 3">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Caption Text</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
  </div> <!-- Carousel -->
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 3000
})
```

See it also on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/62n97s12/).